# Is it allowed to tell OPs to google for recipes instead?

Tags: discussion

So I found [this answer](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/91437/34942), downvoted and left a comment so the OP can edit their question but they're referring to google for recipe searching as this is not a recipe-writing site.

On my main site (AskUbuntu) this would still be considered a big no-no, but what's the consensus here???

Comment: Do you mean "edit their *answer*"? Usually OP (original poster) refers to the question author, and you say question, but you've only commented on the answer. Also... if you're going to bring AskUbuntu into it I'd be careful, in particular to double-check the actual policies and clearly state what is and isn't okay. I highly doubt it's completely unacceptable to ever suggest a Google search there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's completely fine to suggest how to go about finding recipes, including Google, especially if it's clear what to search for. Example terms/queries can be very helpful. It's also fine to include an example recipe in an answer (likely a link, possibly with a quoted excerpt), as long as it really is just an example, not the core of the answer.

Keep in mind that the *question* also needs to not be actively asking for recipes. If it is, then the first step is to fix the question, though regular users should also know not to answer recipe request questions.

A couple things that *aren't* okay:

- Saying "Google it" to provide key information - that belongs in the answer. We also discourage linking to important information without summarizing in the answer; replacing that with a suggestion to search makes it even worse.
- Being in any way negative about this, e.g. LMGTFY links. Suggestions to search need to be clearly about helping provide information.

Comment: Thank you, editing answer to mke it clearer and removing my downvote.